# Search for multiple attributes for single layer with Leaflet Search Control?

Tags: leaflet, search

Edit: I am working on a project where I want to search through a GeoJSON, based on different attributes. To do this I am using [leaflet-search](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search) plugin.

I want to search through my single GeoJSON. That GeoJSON has multiple attributes. I'm wondering if we could pass an array through the `propertyName` option.

```
var controlSearch = new L.Control.Search({
        layer: univ,
        initial: false,
        collapsed: true,
        textPlaceholder: 'Search for University or Department',
        propertyName: ['Institutio','Department'] ,
        hideMarkerOnCollapse: true,
        moveToLocation:function(latlng, title, map) {
            latlng.layer.setIcon(theIcon())
            map.setView(latlng, 13); 
        },  
        marker: false,
});
```

I've tried passing both my attributes as an array but that doesn't work. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I'm using this plugin:
https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search

Comment: I've edited it. Do you have any idea how to tackle this issue?

Comment: There is a simple solution if you don't mind drop down list of candidates and result itself containing both properties.

Comment: This means the user decides which property to search through...

Comment: No both are displayed one besides the other, like "Some Institute, Some department".

Comment: Yes but that means 2 search controls. I want to use 1.

Comment: This can be done in one control, if search text composition and display is OK with you.

Comment: How? Can you explain in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trick to search through multiple properties is to create combined search property when loading GeoJSON layer.

Code could look something like this:

```
var univ = L.geoJSON(data, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer.feature.properties.searchItem = layer.feature.properties.Institutio + ', ' + layer.feature.properties.Department;
  }
};

var controlSearch = new L.Control.Search({
  layer: univ,
  initial: false,
  collapsed: true,
  textPlaceholder: 'Search for University or Department',
  propertyName: 'searchItem' ,
  hideMarkerOnCollapse: true,
  moveToLocation:function(latlng, title, map) {
    latlng.layer.setIcon(theIcon())
    map.setView(latlng, 13); 
  },  
  marker: false,
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly.